# Using a button to add 2 weeks to a date

Tags: ios, swift, date, date-formatting, days

Okay I have been trying to figure this out for a few days. I'm a super beginner, I have a label. In that label I have displayed the date 1/20/21. I was able to do that. Then I have a button. I want each click of that button to add 14 days to the date. That’s it. Here is my code. Please help me. I don't know what to write as the code for the button. I don't understand how to use the methods and what goes in which brackets.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController5: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!

    @IBAction func ContButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        let someDateTime = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 632880000)

        time.text = dateFormatter.string(from: someDateTime)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
```

Comment: Hi Graham, add a couple more tags to the question so people who can help you and are familiar with iOS, etc can find it. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add days to a date in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570546/how-to-add-days-to-a-date-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func ContButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

               // let previousDate = "2017-06-29"
                  let previousDate = time.text
                let currentDate = Date()
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                let previousDateFormated : Date? = dateFormatter.date(from: previousDate)
                let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 14, to: (previousDateFormated)! )
                print(date!)
                time.text = date

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
          let date = Date()
          let formatter = DateFormatter()
          formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
          let result = formatter.string(from: date)
          time.text = result
}
```