# How to get the today's and tomorrow's date in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, time, swift4

How to get the current date in `unix-epoch`?
`timeIntervalSince1970` prints the current time. Is there any way to get today's time at 12 AM?

For example, The current time is : Jan 7, 2018 5:30 PM. `timeIntervalSince1970` will print the current time i.e. `1546903800000`. 
Current date in epoch system will be Jan 7, 2018 00:00 AM. i.e `1546848000000`

Comment: What’s different from the value you get from the value you want?

Comment: `Date().timeIntervalSince1970` - should be the number of seconds from the unix epoch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Unix Epoch Time in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096602/get-unix-epoch-time-in-swift)

Comment: [How to add days to a date in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570546/how-to-add-days-to-a-date-in-swift-3) should give you starting point for the second part .. and you shouldn't be using `Calendar` in Java anymore either

Comment: @MadProgrammer This will add the today's time from 12 AM. I just want the date which is today's date @ 00:00:00 . (hour: minute: second)

Comment: @AmitPal And what makes you think you'd use a different approach? Start with the provided examples and consult the documentation. You question is to broad and is not that uncommon as to not be answered before, you will need to make a further attempts

Comment: @MadProgrammer As I mentioned  `Date(). timeIntervalSince1970 ` will give you the current time since 1970. I need today's date (12 AM) only since 1970

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would do this with components.

Assuming you need time in seconds as defined by [`time(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/time). If you need in milliseconds as defined by [`time(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/time), then you can multiply it out by 1000.

```
// Get right now as it's `DateComponents`.
let now = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: .current, from: Date())

// Create the start of the day in `DateComponents` by leaving off the time.
let today = DateComponents(year: now.year, month: now.month, day: now.day)
let dateToday = Calendar.current.date(from: today)!
print(dateToday.timeIntervalSince1970)

// Add 1 to the day to get tomorrow.
// Don't worry about month and year wraps, the API handles that.
let tomorrow = DateComponents(year: now.year, month: now.month, day: now.day! + 1)
let dateTomorrow = Calendar.current.date(from: tomorrow)!
print(dateTomorrow.timeIntervalSince1970)
```

You can get yesterday by subtracting 1.

---

If you need this in the universal time (UTC, GMT, Z… whatever name you give universal time), then use the following.

```
let utc = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
let now = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: utc, from: Date())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please multiply `timeIntervalSince1970 ` with `1000` for the full fledge solution

Comment: It's all in what you want I suppose. [`time(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/time) is in seconds, but [`time(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/time) is in milliseconds. I'm old, so I assumed `time(2)`.

Answer (score 26):

This can be done very simply using the following code. No need for date components or other complications.

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
// Use the following line if you want midnight UTC instead of local time
//calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
let today = Date()
let midnight = calendar.startOfDay(for: today)
let tomorrow = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: midnight)!

let midnightEpoch = midnight.timeIntervalSince1970
let tomorrowEpoch = tomorrow.timeIntervalSince1970
```

Answer (score 12):

Use this extension to get today's and tomorrow's date

```
extension Date {
   static var tomorrow:  Date { return Date().dayAfter }
   static var today: Date {return Date()}
   var dayAfter: Date {
      return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())!
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Also try adding following code in date extension:

```
extension Date
{
    var startOfDay: Date 
    {
        return Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)
    }

    func getDate(dayDifference: Int) -> Date {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.day = dayDifference
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to:startOfDay)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to get any date by adding days or months or years
by specifying the Calendar Component and the increment value of this component:

```
func getSpecificDate(byAdding component: Calendar.Component, value: Int) -> Date {

    let noon = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)!

    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: component, value: value, to: noon)!
}
```

Where the component wil be one from the following option :
( .day , .month , .year ) and the value will be the amount you want to add for this component

for example to get the next year date you can use the following code:

```
var nextYear = getSpecificDate(byAdding: .year, value: 1).timeIntervalSince1970
```